# How do I add a specific attachment name to subject when replying/forwarding/sending?

Tags: vba

I'm new here, but I became very interested in VBA and macros to help me keep my mailbox organized.
The situation in short - I'm working in a translation office and whenever a client requests a translation, I'm sending them a quote for our services (Quote XXXX.pdf).

I found the following string to add the attachment name to the mail subject:

```
Private WithEvents Mail As Outlook.MailItem
Private WithEvents Inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set Inspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub Inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
  If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    Set Mail = Inspector.CurrentItem
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Mail_AttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment)
  Mail.Subject = " / (" & Attachment.DisplayName & ")"
End Sub
```

HOWEVER it only replaces the old subject with the attachment name (and adds " / ()" to it) no matter what is being attached. My Mail Signature also contains a small image file, so sometimes the name of the image is being copied to the subject line.

I have 2 questions and would highly appreciate any help with them:

1. How do I make it ADD the attachment name, not replace the old subject so it looks like

> Old subject text / (Quote XXXX.pdf)

2. How do I make this macro applicable only to the quotes (add attachment name to subject only if attachment contains "Quote")?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it looks like I found a solution for this myself. Here's the updated script:

```
Private WithEvents Mail As Outlook.MailItem 
Private WithEvents Inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()   
Set Inspectors = Application.Inspectors 
End Sub

Private Sub Inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)   
  If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    Set Mail = Inspector.CurrentItem   
  End If 
End Sub

Private Sub Mail_AttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment)   
  If Attachment.DisplayName Like "*Quote*" Then
    Mail.Subject = Mail.Subject & " / " & Attachment.DisplayName   
  End If 
End Sub
```